# ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Project Error when npm start

Tags: angularjs, npm, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I use [ASP.NET Boilerplate Framework](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) that is based on `.Net Core` and `Angular`. I follow directives in [this page](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular) step by step but when I run npm start I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-animations-js' in'D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src'
resolve 'web-animations-js' in 'D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    resolve as module
      D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Project_Net\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules
        using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/web-animations-js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js doesn't exist
      looking for modules in D:\node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          D:\node_modules\web-animations-js doesn't exist
        .ts
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          D:\node_modules\web-animations-js.ts doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          D:\node_modules\web-animations-js.js doesn't exist
        as directory
          D:\node_modules\web-animations-js doesn't exist
      looking for modules in D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules
        using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/web-animations-js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js doesn't exist
      looking for modules in D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src
        using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src/web-animations-js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js doesn't exist
      looking for modules in D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src
        using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\package.json (relative path: ./src/web-animations-js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js doesn't exist
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\node_modules]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\node_modules]
[D:\Project_Net\node_modules]
[D:\node_modules\package.json]
[D:\node_modules\web-animations-js\package.json]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js]
[D:\node_modules\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.ts]
[D:\node_modules\web-animations-js.ts]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.js]
[D:\node_modules\web-animations-js.js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js]
[D:\node_modules\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.ts]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js.js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\node_modules\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.ts]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.ts]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js.js]
[D:\Project_Net\MyProjSPA\angular\src\web-animations-js]
 @ ./src/polyfills.ts 36:0-27
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

Here are my framework versions:

```
npm -v // 3.10.10
node -v // 6.11.3
tsc -v //2.5.3
ng -v // @angular/core 4.4.4
angular-cli version in `package.json` : //@angular/cli": "^1.3.2"
```

I think it's related to angular version or typescript version.Am I right?
What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in `angular/package.json`:

```
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1"
```

Uncomment this in `angular/src/polyfills.ts`:

```
import 'web-animations-js';
```

Comment: I have two `web-animations-js` in `polyfills.ts` one for `IE` and another for `Firefox`. I Uncomment  `web-animations-js` for firefox but I still have the same error. But when I run `npm install --save web-animations-js` and then `nmp-install` the project successfully compiled. Can explain more about that

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been fixed in v3.2 release. get the latest version.

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/122

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v3.2